# Find total number of palindrome of size N using K letters

Tags: algorithm, permutation, dynamic-programming, palindrome, discrete-mathematics

Find total number of palindromes of length N using K letters such that any prefix of length 2 to N-1 is not a palindrome.

tried `K*((K-1)^(Math.ceil((N-2)/2)))`
first place can hold K letters. second can K-1 except one that is at first place. Similarly for third.
Since half of the places we need to fill with letters rest will follow the same to make it palindrome. But its not correct solution.

Comment: Do the $K$ letters have to be distinct? How do you know your solution is incorrect? What is incorrect about it? You tagged dynamic programming, but your solution does not involve DP -- do you have a reason to think it should?

Comment: Yes K letters are distinct but you can use them multiple times in same string. It may require DP to solve this problem but not sure. This solution doesn't contain all possible such palindromic strings.

Answer (score 1):

Denote `M = \ceil{N / 2}`. The formula is hinged on a simple observation that if a palindrome of length `N` has a nontrivial (i.e. of length at least `2`) palindromic prefix of length less than `N`, then it has a nontrivial palindromic prefix of length at most `M`.

If we denote by `f(n)` the number of *good* palindromes of length `n` (those without a palindromic prefix of length between `2` and `n - 1`), we can compute `f(N)` by subtracting the number of *bad* palindromes form the total number of palindromes, which is `K^M`. By the observation above, each bad palindrome has a *minimal* nontrivial palindromic prefix of length `L` between `2` and `M` (inclusive), which has to be a good palindrome. There are `f(L)` such prefixes for each `L`, and any of them can be extended to a palindrome of length `N` in `K^{M - L}` ways, so

```
f(2) = K
f(N) = K^M - \sum_{L=2}^{M} K^{M - L}f(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script to check [Łukasz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106412/11458991) for small values of `N` and `K`.

Playground: https://ideone.com/7Nk41y

```py
import functools
import itertools
import string


@functools.lru_cache()
def f(N, K):
    if N == 2:
        return K
    M = (N + 1)//2
    return K**M - sum(K**(M - L) * f(L, K) for L in range(2, M+1))


def is_palindrome(s):
    return s[:(len(s) + 1)//2] == s[len(s)//2:][::-1]


def brutal_f(N, K):
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase[:K]
    ret = 0
    for t in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=N):
        s = "".join(t)
        if is_palindrome(s) and not any(is_palindrome(s[:i]) for i in range(2, N)):
            ret += 1
    return ret


print(all(
        f(N, K) == brutal_f(N, K)
        for N in range(12)
        for K in range(4)
    ))
```